# How to resolve the Exception - Error in adding payment - PayUMoney?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, payumoney, payu

I have integrated PayUMoney Payment Gateway using Nodejs and Reactjs. I got Exception like **Error in adding payment**. Anybody help me to resolve this exception !!!

Comment: Can you please tell if you were able to resolve this error and how?